# Android Test App perform programming steps backwards

Tags: android, delphi

I am using Delphi Enterprise version 10.2.3 with Android SDK ver 24.3.3 32bit. I tried a very simple program with only one button. The Onclick is simply the following:

```
ShowMessage('1');
ShowMessage('2');
ShowMessage('3');
ShowMessage('4');
```

The result I got on my Samsung phone when clicking on the button is:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Of course I am expecting to get

```
1
2
3
4
```

This is not my first Android Program. The previous ones runs smoothly. But when I got strange errors on my latest program, I found that programming steps are carried out in reverse. I am also scared now to recompile the previous apps, just in case I am getting this strange behavior. So I just make a new program (above) to test, but got the same results. I also disabled the Antivirus Avast program, and even try it on another Samsung device.

Help will be very much appreciated. At this moment I am really confused and not sure what next steps to take to solve the problem. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On mobile platforms, `ShowMessage` behaves asynchronously. The call finishes instantaneously, it does not wait for the user to close the dialog box.

Try this code:

```
function TForm1.MyShowMessage(const Msg: String): TModalResult;
var
  MR: TModalResult;
begin
  MR := mrNone;
  TDialogService.MessageDialog(Msg, TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation,const  [TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, TMsgDlgBtn.mbNo], TMsgDlgBtn.mbYes, 0,
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
  ﻿    MR := AResult;
    end);
  while MR = mrNone do begin
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    CheckSynchronize;
  end;
  Result := MR;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you @fpiette, just by reading your post many other things now clear to me.

Comment: Even though ShowMessage is asynchronous, one would still expect it to be qieed and displayed in the correct order in which it is called, not in reverse order. Do you have a better explanation for that behavior?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm sure it is shown in correct order. The reason why it seems that it is shown in wrong order is the fact that for each message a new topmost window is created. So when first message is shown its windows is shown on top o all application windows. When second message is shown it is again shown on top od all application windows including window from first message. So in the end you actually end up showing four message windows at same time but since they have same relative position only last one (topmost) is seen.

Comment: Using `Application.ProcessMessages` on Android is not supported and can freeze application. Example in this answer is not proper solution for anything. Since question does not really explain what is the real purpose of using several show messages in the row, it is impossible to give adequate solution to the problem, besides stating that dialogs on Android are asynchronous.